# Filter Common Field Value in One each <Record> Target Field Tag and others in individual <Record> Field Tags using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

Need Help on the below XSLT scenario

````
```

    Input Payload:
    ===============
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <CustomerRecord>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY</chargename>
            <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>XYZ</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
           <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
           <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
           <customer_number>EP10024</customer_number>
        </Customer>
            <Customer>
            <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
            <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
           <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
            <chargename>DAV</chargename>
           <customer_number>EP10022</customer_number>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerRecord>```
````

**Below is the Expected Output**

````
 ```Expected Output Payload:
    ===========================
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root>
        <Customer_PO>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
                <chargename>GARY</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
                <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10025</customer_number>
            </Customer>
        </Customer_PO>
        <Customer_PO>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>XYZ</chargeto>
                <chargename>DAV</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>CDE</chargeto>
                <chargename>GARY DAVIS</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10023</customer_number>
            </Customer>
        </Customer_PO>
        <Customer_Faulty>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
                <chargename>DAV</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10024</customer_number>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <chargeto>ABC</chargeto>
                <chargename>DAV</chargename>
                <customer_number>EP10022</customer_number>
            </Customer>
        </Customer_Faulty>
    </Root>```
````

**I have below XSLT which is partially working fine**

````
 ``` XSLT Code:
    ===============
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:key name="cust-by-charge" match="Customer" use="customer_number" />
        <xsl:template match="/CustomerRecord">
            <Root>
                <Customer_PO>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Customer[count(key('cust-by-charge', customer_number)) > 1]"/>
                </Customer_PO>
                <Customer_Faulty>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Customer[count(key('cust-by-charge', customer_number)) = 1]"/>
                </Customer_Faulty>
            </Root>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    ```
````

**I am partially getting output correctly, I need to create multiple <Customer_PO> segments for the common <customer_number> field values.
In our current case all common values are getting added into same <Customer_PO>. --> This part is not working fine

And Non Common <customer_number> field values will be set under <Customer_Faulty> -- This part is working Fine**

Comment: Please give your questions more meaningful titles, so that they can help others too.

Comment: I deleted the xslt-2 and xslt-3 tags, since I assume that if you were able to use `xsl:for-each-group` then you would do so.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think you are drawing the wrong conclusion - see OP's previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73354842/need-help-on-xslt

Comment: You might be right. But I can't see why anyone would write an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet for this problem if they know 2.0 exists and are prepared to use it.

Comment: @MichaelKay I wrote the above stylesheet because I thought that was the best solution to OP's **previous** problem. As it happens, it is compatible with XSLT 1.0, so I tagged it as such.

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

I am again struggling to understand your explanation. I *think* this does what you want:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CustomerRecord">
    <xsl:variable name="groups">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Customer" group-by="customer_number">
            <group size="{count(current-group())}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Root>
        <xsl:for-each select="$groups/group[@size > 1]">
            <Customer_PO>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Customer"/>
            </Customer_PO>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <Customer_Faulty>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$groups/group[@size = 1]/Customer"/>
        </Customer_Faulty>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```